# Handle decomposition of closed $4$-dimensional manifold

Tags: geometric-topology

I am trying to understand handles. So I have seen some easy examples in lower dimensions but I want to understand some (slightly) higher dimensional ones. So let $M$ be a closed $4$ dimensional manifold and let us say that it admits a handle decomposition with $3$ handles, to not make it too complicated. Can someone give me an example of such a case? (I guess a classification of those is too hard).